# Material angular auto complete: how to remains the mat-option in the screen after selecting an option?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using the [Material auto complete angular](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview).
After i select one option in my `mat-option` list, my `mat-options` hide. I need to remain the options after select. Gif showing the problem:

[image]

**My html**

```
<div class="col-xl-6 margemColunas">
    <label>Anunciaremos nas contas *</label>
     <input class="form-control inputContasB2W"
          #inputContasB2W
          [formControl]="contasB2WControl"
          [matAutocomplete]="auto"
          (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event, i)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let contaB2W of contasFiltradas | async" [value]="contaB2W">
          {{contaB2W}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
</div>

<div class="col-xl-6 alinhaChips">
  <mat-chip-list>
    <mat-chip
    *ngFor="let contaB2W of produto.contasAnunciarB2W; let j = index"
    [selectable]="selected"
    [removable]="removable"
    (removed)="removeTag(i, j)">
    {{contaB2W}}
    <mat-icon matChipRemove><i class="fa fa-close"></i></mat-icon>
  </mat-chip>
  </mat-chip-list>
</div>
```

**My ts:**

```
constructor(){
    this.contasFiltradas = this.contasB2WControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(null),
      map((nomeConta: string | null) => nomeConta ? this._filter(nomeConta) : this.contasB2W.slice()));
}

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    return this.contasB2W.filter(conta => conta.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) === 0);
  }

selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent, index: number): void {

 this.produtosConfirmadosAnuncio[index].contasAnunciarB2W.push(event.option.viewValue);

    this.inputContasB2W.nativeElement.value = '';

          } 
        }
```

Comment: Stopping event propagation may do it. Try calling `event.stopPropagation();` inside `selected` method.

Comment: @GCSDC - MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent does not have stopPropagation. How to do that?

Comment: I think you may use `event.preventDefault`.

Answer (score 0):

I used workaround to `blur()` and then `focus()` again the input.

In ts:

```
@ViewChild('inputContasB2W') autocompleteInput: ElementRef;

selected(event: MatAutocompleteSelectedEvent) {
  [..do your stuff...]

  this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.blur();
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.autocompleteInput.nativeElement.focus();
    }, 100
  );
}
```

If you want to preserve input text you have to save it in `_filter()` and set the value again before `blur()` like `this.contasB2WControl.setValue(this.lastFilterValue);`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is relatively simple. You have to stop the propagation of the click, but when the click reaches the `mat-option` it is already too late. Then an invisible prelayer is added with a `span` tag:

```html
...
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let contaB2W of contasFiltradas | async" [value]="contaB2W" 
   style="position: relative;">
    <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;"
     (click)="doWhateverWith(contaB2W); $event.stopPropagation()">
      {{contaB2W}}
    </span>
  </mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
...
```

- Added a `span` with style `position: absolute` with `top,left,bottom,right` set to `0`.
- Added `position: relative` style to `mat-option` so that the span expands correctly.
- The `(click)` event is added to handle the item in the `span`, since it will be the last one to receive the click event.
- The `$event.stopPropagation()` is added in this same `span`

This should be more than enough.

Answer (score -1):

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="New fruit..."
        #input
        #trigger="matAutocompleteTrigger" // <-- get trigger ref
        [formControl]="control"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      />
      <mat-autocomplete
        #auto="matAutocomplete"
        (optionSelected)="selected($event)"
      >
        <mat-option
          *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async"
          [value]="option"
          (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); trigger.openPanel()" // <-- use it here
        >
          {{ option }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: This doesn't prevent the option panel from closing. Nor does it re-open it in Angular 12/Material 12 if you are using `(optionSelected)` on the `<mat-autocomplete>`. And even without that, it only works the first time...